# Which file systems support splicing via Linux's splice(2)?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, splice, zero-copy

The [man page for the `splice` system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice) says that `splice` may fail and set `errno` to `EINVAL` if:

> Target file system doesn't support splicing; neither of the descriptors refers to a pipe; or offset given for non-seekable device

Which file systems support splicing?

Comment: Why does something think this belongs on Serverfault?

Comment: Nice information. Didn't know splice before. system calls are usually called and implemented by programmers. I think it is therefore a valid stack overflow question.

Comment: If you had a program that wanted to splice to output files, and you were choosing what filesystem to use for a system to run it on, then it's a sysadmin question, not a programming question.  Looks like this is what's getting asked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My original answer was partially incorrect, this is a major rewrite.

### Linux 2.6.30.10 and below

In Linux 2.6.30.10 and older, `splice` returns `EINVAL` when the source or target filesystem does not support splicing.  Here are the **filesystems that do support splicing**:

- **in read mode**: adfs, affs, afs, bfs, btrfs, coda, ecryptfs, exofs, ext2, ext3, ext4, fat, fuse, hpfs, jffs2, jfs, minix, nfs, nilfs2, ntfs, ocfs2, omfs, qnx4, reiserfs, smbfs, sysv, ubifs, udf, ufs.
- **in write mode**: exofs, ext2, ext3, ext4, jfs, ocfs2, reiserfs, ubifs.

*Details follow.  Support for splicing in determined in the [`do_splice_to()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.30.10/fs/splice.c#L932) function in the "file to pipe" case and in the [`do_splice_from()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.30.10/fs/splice.c#L908) function in the "pipe to file" case.  It is done by checking whether the relevant `struct file_operations` contains `.splice_read` or `.splice_write`, respectively.  In order to produce the above lists of filesystems, I've grepped `fs/*/file.c` for `.splice_read` and `.splice_write`*.

### Linux 2.6.31 and above

Starting with Linux 2.6.31, **all the filesystems support splicing both in read and write modes**.

*Details follow.  When a filesystem does not have `.splice_read` or `.splice_write` in its `struct file_operations`, a fallback function is used: `default_file_splice_read` and `default_file_splice_write`, respectively.  See [`do_splice_to()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.31/fs/splice.c#L1087) and [`do_splice_from()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.31/fs/splice.c#L1060) for implementations.  Note: `EINVAL` may still be returned for other reasons listed in the documentation.*

Comment: I've noticed that starting from Linux 2.6.31 there's a fallback splicing for every filesystem.  Hence a major rewrite.

Comment: So Linux 2.6.31 and above support splicing to/from a FUSE filesystem as well?

Comment: @Daniel I've successfully run the code from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580923/ on my Linux 2.6.32-23 with fuse filesystem (via sshfs) as target.

Answer (score 0):

Accordding to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580923/how-can-i-use-linuxs-splice-function-to-copy-a-file-to-another-file), EXT3 does. It seems that you might be out of luck with any FUSE file system.